# Boot in UEFI mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bootloader, grub-efi

I have ubuntu 14.10 installed on a pendrive in legacy mode. I can use it to boot my desktop and tablet in legacy mode, but not UEFI. Is there any way to make it bootable in UEFI mode? For example, adding an EFI partition and copying grub2 to it? Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way is to reinstall ubuntu . Boot the live media with uefi enabled. You might be able to do this with boot-repair, I am not sure. EFI boot is NOT copying grub to a EFI partition. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_EFI_mode

Comment: You must use the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Shrink the existing partition by a little bit, create a new EFI System Partition (ESP) in the space, and install a Linux boot loader on it. A few caveats:

- I do *not* recommend using GRUB for this task. You may need to hand-craft your configuration file, and with GRUB this is far too difficult to do. Instead, select almost any other [EFI boot loader for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html) that you like. My own [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is likely to be easy to set up, and will enable users to boot other installed OSes, too. (OTOH, you might not want that last feature.) ELILO and SYSLINUX are also likely to be relatively easy to configure. If you expect to update your kernels on the drive, be aware that most boot loaders will require updates to their configuration files to match. (rEFInd is an exception to this rule; it auto-detects kernels on each boot.)
- You must install your EFI boot loader as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` on the ESP. (Assuming you're targeting 64-bit systems.) Normally, EFI boot loaders go to other names and register themselves with the computer's NVRAM; but to boot on multiple computers, you must use the fallback filename of `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. My [EFI boot loader installation page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html) covers this topic in more detail.
- EFI systems normally boot from [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) disks. Your USB drive probably uses the older [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partitioning scheme instead. In theory, MBR should be OK, but you should be aware that an MBR ESP has a type code of 0xEF. Also, it's entirely possible that some computers will refuse to boot from an MBR flash drive. If you run into this problem, you may need to convert from MBR to GPT. You can do this with `gdisk`, but then you'll need to re-install a BIOS-mode boot loader.