# Switching to UEFI Boot without fresh installation or boot repair tool

Tags: grub2, uefi, bootloader

I deleted every partition in my hdd and started with a fresh installation of Ubuntu(14.04). The **EFI** partition was also deleted. Now I can boot into Ubuntu only if I change the **boot mode** to **Legacy** . 
So, I created a new partition using Gparted and it is `/dev/sda4` mounted on `/boot/efi`. This is a `FAT32` `Primary` partition of size `250 MiB` and carries a `boot` flag. I have the following lines in my `/etc/fstab` :

```
# /boot/efi on /dev/sda1
UUID=2A52-CEE8                            /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
```

1) I know that this partition is supposed to hold some file similar to those of `grub`. But I am not sure how to proceed. I found this [guide](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html) from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596293/boot-in-uefi-mode) . But is this the right way to proceed? I am running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS on a Lenovo Y510P laptop.

2) Please note that I am not interested in a fresh installation keeping my EFI partition. But I am curious if that will automatically install required bootloader files in the EFI partition?

3) I am also not interested in using Boot Repair Tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install an EFI boot loader. There are several ways to do this:

- GRUB 2 is the default Ubuntu boot loader.

  - I know you said you don't want to use it, but [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is the easiest way to install GRUB 2 in your situation.
  - You can do it manually, but I don't have a URL handy for step-by-step instructions on doing this.
- My [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) can be installed by first using the CD-R or USB flash drive version to boot into the main Ubuntu installation and then installing the PPA or Debian package.
- Several other EFI boot loaders are available; see [my page on the subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html) for a rundown. Aside from GRUB 2 and rEFInd, these all require manual configuration and maintenance whenever you update your kernel. (Note that automatic kernel updates come out roughly once every couple of weeks.)

Overall, the two easiest approaches are to use Boot Repair to install GRUB 2 or to install rEFInd.

Comment: I am doing this more to develop an understanding of bootloaders. So, I think I will first try your bootloader with information on your page.